# The type or namespace name 'Support' does not exist in Xamarin Android project

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

I had a Xamarin Android project which worked fine until i 've moved the folder of the project to another folder. 
After that i am taking the error 
**The type or namespace name 'Support' does not exist in the namespace 'Android' (are you missing an assembly reference?)** 
I tried to unistall and install again from nuget the Xamarin.Android.Support.Design but nothing.
Do you have any ideas what is going wrong?

Comment: Try to delete the folder 'bin' and 'obj',then rebuild your project.

Comment: I did but nothing. Still the same error

Comment: See this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/65825218/2477758. There could be a difference in target Android version in AndroidManifest.xml and Android.csproj.