# Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android does not exist after Xamarin update from 2.5 to 3.5

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have updated my projects Xamarin.Forms NuGet package from version 2.5 to 3.5. After this update I got an error in my Android project saying:

> The type or namespace name 'Android' does not exist in the namespace
>   'Xamarin.Forms.Platform' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

What I've tried so far:

- Delete bin, obj folders
- Close and Reopen solution
- Clean and Rebuild solution
- Reinstalling Xamarin Forms NuGet

Comment: Install the same version for xamarin forms into the Android and iOS project.

Comment: @Jaymin There is no iOS or UWP project.

Comment: Make sure an android project has the same version as Form has.

Comment: @Jaymin Versions are the same.

Comment: never insert code as an image, I have seen this issue a lot lately and the solution is quite simple, uninstall XF from everywhere, close vs and clear all bin obj, restart the project and reinstall the XF package and you are done

Comment: @G.hakim Have tried this also. Uninstalled all NuGet packages, deleted all the code. Basically I'm left with clean solution. Only place where I have code is the part in my screenshot (1 line), that's it. Have tried different combinations of all the things you mentioned, still the same. The only option I can think of doing is to create new project, copy the Android part to old one, copy all the code..
And regarding the screenshot, I wanted to explicitly show where I get red squiggly.

Comment: What is your VS version btw I have a feeling I know what you are going through are yo somehow using VS17 V15.9.1?

Comment: @G.hakim My VS17 version is 15.9.6. After many different solutions I thought I would try to update to version Xamarin 3.4 and it worked!!! What is so special about v3.5 remains unknown :) I'm leaving this question open just in case I manage to update to 3.5.

Comment: Thank you for this comment. I had the same issue and downgrading to Xamarin 3.4 actually worked. I have no idea why, though...

Comment: Xamarin ... devised by chimps for us chumps ...

Answer (score 6):

Edit: 15 March 2022

I updated the target Android version in Android Manifest.xml file.

Next I had to update `TargetFramework` version with below steps

1. Go to Android Project Options (Double click on Android project or right click -> options).
2. Now select **Build** -> **Compile using Android version: (Target Framework)**.

[image: Screenshot of Android Project Settings showing General build settings.]

Alternatively for updating the target version, you can manually do so by editing the project .csproj file. Doing so, will display a prompt to reload the project. Please reload it.

Steps to edit the project file in VS for Mac.

1. Right click on the Android project and select "Edit project File" option.
2. Edit the `<TargetFrameworkVersion>v11.0</TargetFrameworkVersion>` to your target version. I have added v11.0 as the target here.
3. Save the project and accept the reload prompt. you're good to go.

You should not be seeing the compiler error again, if the Android target version is the root cause.

Answer (score 3):

@Jaymin is right. You must make sure that the version of the installed Xamarin.Android should be as same as the version that you have added to the current project.

For example, if you have installed v27.0.2.1 of Xamarin.Android, you can not upgrade your project to v28.0.0.1 only. You should upgrade the component(Xamarin.Android) which is installed with Visual Studio first.

Answer (score 2):

Versions were the same when the problem presented itself in my case (and the OP). After trying many things...

The solution was: Delete the Xamarin.Forms.x.x.xxxxxx (currently installed version) NuGet file folder in MySolution\Packages folder. Then, upgrade the Android Project nuget project.

I also deleted all old version folders of Xamarin.Forms from my packages folder first.

Answer (score 0):

Update the Xamarin.forms to version 4.3.0.991250 and it's compatible with Android 8.1
Compile and builds.