# Cannot locate Xamarin.Forms.Platform, Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android pdb symbols

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, pdb-files

I cannot locate or load a compatible symbol (pdb) file for *`Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.dll`*.

I'm debugging a standard "Blank" template Xamarin App from Visual Studio, which by default includes the following dependencies:

[image]

I'm trying to step into the call to `LoadApplication` from `OnCreate`.

However I cannot locate the *`Xamarin.Forms.Platform.pdb`* or *`Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.pdb`* files in the directory *`C:\Microsoft\Xamarin\NuGet\xamarin.forms\4.4.0.991265\lib\netstandard2.0`* that the other above assemblies' pdb files are located in and can be manually loaded from (*`Xamarin.Forms.Core.pdb`*, *`Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.pdb`*):

[image]

I did locate *`Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.pdb`* (though curiously not *`Xamarin.Forms.Platform.pdb`*) in some other locations (*`C:\Users\_\source\repos\XFwMvx\XFwMvx\XFwMvx.Android\obj\Debug\90\android\assets`* and *`C:\Microsoft\Xamarin\NuGet\xamarin.forms\4.4.0.991265\lib\MonoAndroid90`*) but was given an error when trying to manually load them from the Modules window:

[image]

Comment: Please try to clean and rebuild the project, sometimes this works as a charm.

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT Of course... I just don't understand why if it is open source that there is no `pdb` file for `Xamarin.Forms.Platform.dll` in particular (especially being only 14kb)?

Comment: Please see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/65825218/2477758. The target version in AndroidManifest.xml and the Android.csproj target framework might be different.