# Xamarin Android project compilation errors after libraries upgrade

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm working on an old Xamarin project because we need to release a new IOS version of the mobile application.
This required these library upgrades:

```
Xamarin Forms: 2.3.3.193 -> 4.8.0.1687
Xamarin Auth: 1.3.0 -> 1.7.0
```

After that I was forced to update also these libraries in the Android Project:

```
Xamarin.Android.Support.*: 28.0.0.1 -> 28.0.0.3
```

Now I have a lot of compilation problems in Android Project. First of all this import:

```
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;
```

now cause this error:

```
The type or namespace name 'Android' does not exist in the namespace 'Xamarin.Forms.Platform' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

How I can solve the issue? Now the IOS version of the project works fine but the Android version do not compile.

Comment: [does this help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54591881/xamarin-forms-platform-android-does-not-exist-after-xamarin-update-from-2-5-to-3)? i.e. Jaymin's comment states 'Make sure an android project has the same version as Form has.'

Comment: @nilsK I don't understand the answer. PCL project and Android project have the save Xamarin Forms version. Correct?

Comment: The more i read about this ... i honestly don't know. My guess is: you upgraded Xamarin Froms two major versions, but Xamarin Android only got a patch update (28.0.0.1->28.0.0.3). Also stated in the linked post: 'You should upgrade the component(Xamarin.Android) which is installed with Visual Studio first.'. But with all the suggestions about deleting bin/obj folders and reinstalling everything ... what is wrong with Xamarin? ^^ You'll need to crawl through the docs / roadmaps and figure out whats missing.

Comment: @nilsK the problem was a duplicate reference in .csproj file of the Android project. Anyway thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue:
The problem was a double reference to the library Xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs (28.0.0.1 and 28.0.0.3 versions) in the .csproj file of the Android project.

I removed the old reference to 28.0.0.1 version and I solved all the build problems.
Before that I tried to delete all bin/obj folders and restore all the nuget packages but without success. I don't know if this was the first step to the solution of the problem.

Comment: Don't forget to mark this answer later which will help more people with same problem:).

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT yes, I will do ;)